# Looking for Mysql query

Tags: mysql, database

I have mysql table with following 3 fields:

```
- vouchercode: Unique KEY
- voucherstatus: 1 for unused voucher, 3 for used voucher
- partnerId
```

I want to display how many vouchers are used and unused w.r.t partnerId.

```
Example :- table data 
PartnerId voucherstaus  vouchercode(unique)
1          1
1          3 
1          1
2          3
2          3
2          1


Result:
PartnerId  usedvouchers unusedvouchers
1          1             2
2          2             1
```

Please help me with mysql query for same. Seems i have to use subquery and group by doesn't work. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you tag this with sql-server?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  partnerID,
        SUM(CASE WHEN voucherstatus = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) unusedvouchers,
        SUM(CASE WHEN voucherstatus = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) usedvouchers 
FROM    data
GROUP   BY partnerID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/801e4/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*will work only in MySQL*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/801e4/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
select PartnerId, SUM(case when  voucher_status =1 then 1 else 0 end) as unused, sum(case when  voucher_status =3 then 1 else 0 end) as used from Voucher group by PartnerID;
```

[**sqlfiddle** **demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cce7d/8)